# Conditional replacement of NAs in two dataframes R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, na

Probably simple but tricky question especially for larger data sets. Given two dataframes (`df1`,`df2`) of equal dimensions as below:

```
 head(df1)
          a          b  c
1 0.8569720 0.45839112 NA
2 0.7789126 0.36591578 NA
3 0.6901663 0.88095485 NA
4 0.7705756 0.54775807 NA
5 0.1743111 0.89087819 NA
6 0.5812786 0.04361905 NA
```

and

```
head(df2)
           a         b  c
1 0.21210312 0.7670091 NA
2 0.19767464 0.3050934  1
3 0.08982958 0.4453491  2
4 0.75196925 0.6745908  3
5 0.73216793 0.6418483  4
6 0.73640209 0.7448011  5
```

How can one find all columns where `if(all(is.na(df1))`, in this case `c`, go to `df2`and set all values in matching column (`c`) to `NAs`.

**Desired output**

```
head(df3)
           a         b  c
1 0.21210312 0.7670091 NA
2 0.19767464 0.3050934 NA
3 0.08982958 0.4453491 NA
4 0.75196925 0.6745908 NA
5 0.73216793 0.6418483 NA
6 0.73640209 0.7448011 NA
```

My actual dataframes have more than `140000` columns.

Comment: You can get "empty" columns with this code: `which(colSums(is.na(x)) == nrow(x))`, which is implemented here: https://github.com/sjPlot/sjmisc/blob/master/R/is_empty.R#L94

Comment: So, `df2[, empty_cols(df1)] <- NA` should work (can't test right now, commenting from mobile phone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on the negated logical matrix (`is.na(df1)`), negate (!`) the`vector` so that 0 non-NA elements becomes TRUE and all others FALSE, use this to subset the columns of 'df2' and assign it to NA.

```
df2[!colSums(!is.na(df1))] <- NA
df2
#           a         b  c
#1 0.21210312 0.7670091 NA
#2 0.19767464 0.3050934 NA
#3 0.08982958 0.4453491 NA
#4 0.75196925 0.6745908 NA
#5 0.73216793 0.6418483 NA
#6 0.73640209 0.7448011 NA
```

---

Or another option is to loop over the columns and check whether `all` the elements are NA to create a logical vector for subsetting the columns of 'df2' and assigning it to NA

```
df2[sapply(df1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))] <- NA
```

---

If these are big datasets, another option would be `set` from `data.table` (should be more efficient as this does the assignment in place)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
j1 <-  which(sapply(df1, function(x) all(is.na(x))))

for(j in j1){
   set(df2, i = NULL, j = j, value = NA)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this smart answer. It worked great but takes time to complete on a `df` with `dim = 4779 rows and  141743 columns`.

Comment: @code123  I also added a `data.table` solution.  Please check if that makes any difference